# How Can i open an cmd prompt and set an path to open an .bat file in Vb Script..?

Tags: shell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, qtp

I need to Automate the Whole Process, So the Cmd Prompt opens and path is set there for the .bat file to open
 I have tried with Window Shell Commands to do this .. they  work fine .. But i need some other way to open and set the path to run the file ..can anyone help me

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Comment: I need to launch an application through cmd prompt , this is not happening through shell commands while the system is locked and the automation scripts are running at the background, the application is not getting launched (I need to set path in cmd for the app to open) i have done it through Automation ,problem is shell commands which sets the path for the app (path is not getting set in cmd ) (app is not getting launched)..  Thanks For Asking @Ansgar

Comment: What application? What path? What have you tried so far, and what results did you get? What were the results you expected? What does your batch file look like, and how do you (try to) run it?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
Set WshShell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.AppActivate "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
wshshell.sendkeys "c:\path"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\tmp"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "batch.cmd"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Your code is not valid for QTP/UFT which I assume is where the OP will be using it. Use "CreateObject" instead of "WScript.CreateObject", and change the references to "WScript.Sleep" to "Wait 1" if a pause is really required. WScript does not exist in QTP/UFT.

Comment: you are correct, my code is in vbscript. The question asks for vbscript code.. unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: The OP put the qtp tag in, so my assumption is based on that. In case you're unaware what QTP is, it's an automated testing tool made by HP which uses VBScript as the scripting language, but it adds some things and takes some things away (WScript being one), hence the suggested adjustment (if the OP really is using QTP).

Comment: @serverGuy Thanks Man.. I have already tried it... but the thing is other than window shell commands..is there any other way ..??? because i need to automate it and write an vb script function

Comment: Hey Saddy, Any other way to do what? Set the path? The question that you asked is answered here. Are you actually asking how to change the Windows path? That can be done in your environment variables, and you don't need need a command prompt for that.